# Can I submit multiple versions of the same App to the Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I just sent version 0.9 of my app to the store for initial review by Apple.
I am working on 0.9.1 which will be ready tomorrow. Is there a way I can have more than 1 version of the same application in "Waiting For Review" ?

There doesn't seem to be anything in iTunes Connect for this.

Comment: No, there isn't a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  If you reject the binary of 0.9 in iTunes connect before it is approved, it will allow you to submit a new binary, 0.9.1, for review.  Only the last binary will be reviewed.

Comment: I will try this and close the answer tonight then - I assume it will then restart the 5 days cycle all over again.

Comment: I would only add something, though obvious for many people: The submission will start from the beginning, so if the app was e.g. two days from review, it will start again in the end of the queue.

Comment: Indeed - I decided to take my chances and left the initial submission in. I found a crasher, maybe Apple won't. I only need this approved so I can start testing IAP.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't have more than one at a time. Just submit 0.9.1 once it's ready, and you will be pushed to the end of the Waiting For Review queue.

Comment: Thanks - I could have sworn there was a way to do this a year ago.